# Rails 4: Looping through Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I think I am doing something horribly wrong.
I get this error:

```
TypeError
no implicit conversion of nil into String
```

if I put this in my View (haml):

```
...

- ["Greg", "is", "cool", "ya"].each do |tag|
    .tagwrapper
        = link_to tag.to_s.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), '/search?searchtags='+tag.to_s.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), class: 'smaller half-stretched'

...
```

How am I supposed to do this instead?

Comment: post the whole each block and the exact line where this error is happening ?

Comment: added it, last line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gsub!` returns `nil` if no substitutions were performed.

Remove `!` so it becomes:

`= link_to tag.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), '/search?searchtags='+tag.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, ''), class: 'smaller half-stretched'`

[APIdock Reference](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub%21)

Answer (score 3):

You should check that [`gsub!` isn't returning `nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub-21) in the event that no substitutions are made:

```
# Will make zero passes
replaced_tag = tag.to_s.gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
if replaced_tag
    = link_to tag, '/search?searchtags=' + tag, class: 'smaller half-stretched'
```

Alternatively, in you want to return the string *even if no substitutions are made*, you can use [`gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-gsub) (with the `!` removed):

```
# Will make four passes, one for each ['Greg', 'is', 'cool', 'ya']
replaced_tag = tag.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9A-Za-z]/, '')
if replaced_tag
    = link_to tag, '/search?searchtags=' + tag, class: 'smaller half-stretched'
```